# Authorization Code Grant (WSO2 API Manager 3.2.0 )

Tags: angular, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

1. I created a simple angular application then I configured it as a client for keycloak (client angular-app, realm master)
2. I configured keycloak as an external keymanager for WSO2 APIM (client apim-client, realm master)
3. I launched the following request : http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth?client_id=angular-app&response_type=code&state=fj8o3n7bdy1op5 from the browser to authenticate user to my angular app which redirected me to my angular application and generated an authorization code
4. I used the authorization code generated to get the access token from the /token endpoint => Access token generated successfully

The problem is that I still cannot invoke the APIs published on WSO2 using the access token generated using the authorization code grant and I get the following error from WSO2 server :

```json
{"fault":{"code":900908,"message":"Resource forbidden ","description":"User is NOT authorized to access the Resource. API Subscription validation failed."}}
```

Any recommendation, help ??

Comment: Did you configure key cloak as Key Manager in APIM as suggested in https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/

Comment: yes keycloak is configured successfully as an external key manager for WSO2. I can generate oauth key from the Dev portal using the keycloak keymanager and use it to invoke an API published in WSO2. But I cannot invoke APIs using an oauth key generated from my angular app (authorization grant type) as described earlier

Comment: In devportal, it uses `client-credentials` grant type. May be that's the reason it's working when trying through Dev Portal. Do you see any errors in wso2carbon.log when trying to invoke the API from angular app?

Comment: I just get 900908 code error ( description : User is NOT authorized to access the Resource. API Subscription validation failed )